# Java - getResourceAsStream doesn't work ( Eclipse )

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I try to extract a file which is attached in my "src" folder.

So I wanted to get the Inputstream from the file and write it into for example c:/file.txt

my code:

```
InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
            
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("c:/file.txt");
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
os.close();
is.close();
```

The Error:

> Type mismatch: Eclipse cannot convert from java.io.InputStream to org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream

Answer (score 6):

Remove this import

```
import org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream;
```

from your class, and add

```
import java.io.InputStream
```

Answer (score 1):

You imported the wrong `InputStream`.

Try importing `java.io.InputStream` instead of `org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream`.

Comment: Oh yep! Thank you all very much

Answer (score 1):

Remove import of `org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream` and change it to  `java.io.InputStream`

Answer (score 1):

You have imported wrong class `org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream`. Right class is `java.io.InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported: - `org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream` instead of `java.io.InputStream`?

Check that, and if you have the first import, replace it with later one.